# How to add stateful button to a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have developed a form where I want to add <kbd>Next</kbd> button at the end of form for another form load without page loading. I am not able to achieve this target.

```html
<form action="#" id="form_sample_1" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter the name
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="templateName" type="text" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter Birth Year
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="admissionYear" type="date" name="name" data-required="1" class="form-control" maxlength="4" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Select the type of room
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <select id="levelSelect" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" tabindex="1">
          <option value="0" disabled selected default>--Select--</option>
          <option value="AC">AC</option>
          <option value="non-AC">non-AC</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label1 col-md-4">Enter total number of room
        <span class="required"> * </span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="room">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-3">
        <button id="SubmitEligibility" type="button" class="btn blue">Save &#38 Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

After <kbd>Save & Continue</kbd>, I want to show some other form. Please advise me on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new html button and associate them a script in js:

```
<button id="Next" type="button" onclick="nextFunction();">Next</button>
```

The `js` function is:

```
nextFunction(){
$('#form-group').hide();
$('#newForm').show();
}
```

Comment: An `<input id="next-btn" type="button" value="Next" onclick="nextFunction();" />` will work just as well. Also, the `type="button"` is not necessary.